# Safari and IE not responding to height for menu element

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, safari, css

I am working on Jakoody.com.  In Safari (at least 5.0.5-Lion) and IE 9 and below the browser adds padding to the bottom of the menu thus repeating the background image and showing a double stitch on the bottom.  This also happens to the "stitched-quote" (under the  slider).

I have been searching for a few hours now and haven't found anything that works yet.  Any suggestions?

I am using WordPress with the Headway framework (both latest versions)

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.block` has `box-sizing` property set to **border-box**. This is not supported by all browsers. You can either disable `box-sizing` for `.block` and reduce the `min-height` of `#block-86` (style.css:line 257) to **28px** or reduce the `min-height` of `#block-86` to **28px** for browsers that doesn't support CSS `box-sizing` (Javascript maybe?).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Very helpful!  I have set the `min-height` to 28px for `block-86`. I tried `content-box` for the `box-sizing` and it worked, but it just caused the same issue I just fixed for the other browsers.  I can't find anywhere how to target a specific version of Safari.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Woops, hit enter too soon.  Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up leaving the `box-sizing` to `content-box` then fixing it in the other browsers and it works!!  Thanks a lot.  Not sure what I would have done without your response.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you found this to be the answer, why not select it as answer? ;)

Comment: First post here, sorry haha.  Thanks again!